# Perl : cpan PDL install issue

Tags: perl, cpan, pdl

I have Cygwin under win10 and I try to install PDL lib for Perl in order to use PDL::Matrix

When making cpan install PDL I have make errors I do not manage to solve :

```
    make[3]: *** [Makefile:323: OpenGLQ.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:521: subdirs] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:476: subdirs] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:545: subdirs] Error 2
Failed during this command:
 CHM/PDL-2.019.tar.gz                         : make NO
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Do you have to use cygwin or could you use Strawberry Perl instead?

Comment: I do not have any preferences. I can use either install Active Perl nor Strawberry Perl. I just want  a working Perl developping environement with Eclispe that recognise the libraries such as use Math::Matrix or use PDL. Just please no more "impossible to find xxx in @INC"

Answer (score 1):

The currently-recommended way to use PDL on Windows is Strawberry Perl PDL edition (I use the "portable" version since that also allows me to locate it in a directory with a space to catch bugs).

As of this writing (Mar 2022), PDL gets continuous integration (CI) testing on Cygwin every time it is released, rather than every time a commit is pushed, because Cygwin takes 30+ mins to build, while building the entire, feature-complete library and testing it on all known/working downstream modules (50+ currently) takes about 15. Therefore, it ought to work on Cygwin. Please report specific problems if not.

Answer (score 0):

> This may work better using Windows ( according to my personal experience )

1- If you still haven't tried to install the module using ppm ( manager for modules similar to cpan ) or manually, please do.

2- if the PDL module still don't want to get installed, the best thing to is installing PDL using a repository that have the installation error fixed using next steps :

Be sure to have ppm installed

You can simply install it directly

```
ppm install http://www.sisyphusion.tk/ppm/PDL.ppd
```

OR:
First add the wanted repository to ppm

```
ppm repo add http://www.sisyphusion.tk/ppm
```

Next install PDL using the repository

```
ppm install PDL
```

You can check up more info if you want http://www.sisyphusion.tk/ppm/